# how to combine two same class object into one?

Tags: c#, json

I made a one class that named **Phrases** that includes some strings and integers.

```
public class Phrases {
    public class PhraseData {
        public string text { get; set; }
        public string htmlColor { get; set; }
        public int position { get; set; }
    }

    public PhraseData intro { get; set; }
    public PhraseData credit { get; set; }
    public PhraseData general { get; set; }
    /* and more PhraseDatas... */
}

/* ... */
```

and I have a two json file. one is only have text data of PhraseData, another one have a every data except text data. so If I deserialize these json files. I'll get two **Phrases** class objects like this.

```
Phrases onlyTextFilled;
Phrases everyDataFilledExceptText;
```

I want to combine these two class objects into one. there is any good way to solve this problem?

help me guys!

Comment: Have you tried to combine the 2 JSON Strings before deserialization (I mean join them into one JSON String)?

Comment: @BojanB i tried but i won't works, just got exception.

Comment: can you post how the combined JSON looks like and what Exception you get?

Comment: The simplest way to do this (if combining the 2 JSON strings like @Bojan B suggests doesn't work) would be to simply assign the text of the 1st object to the test property of the 2nd object after deserializing:
`everyDataFilledExceptText.text = onlyTextFilled.text;`

Comment: thanks for good suggestions. I just seperate these classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty. Overload the '+' operator. For the inner class and the main one. Also add attributes to ignore default and null values for your properties (if using Newtonsoft.Json for instance). Another wild thought, you could use the decorator pattern.

```
public class Phrases
{
    public class PhraseData
    {
        [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, Order = 1, DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string text { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, Order = 2, DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string htmlColor { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, Order = 3, DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public int position { get; set; }

        public static PhraseData operator + (PhraseData pd1, PhraseData pd2)
        {
            var pd = new PhraseData();
            pd.text = (pd1.text == null) ? pd2.text : pd1.text;
            pd.htmlColor = (pd1.htmlColor == null) ? pd2.htmlColor : pd1.htmlColor;
            pd.position = (pd1.position == 0) ? pd2.position : pd1.position;
            return pd;
        }
    }

    public PhraseData intro { get; set; }
    public PhraseData credit { get; set; }
    public PhraseData general { get; set; }

    public static Phrases operator + (Phrases p1, Phrases p2)
    {
        return new Phrases() { 
            intro = p1.intro + p2.intro,
            credit = p1.credit + p2.credit,
            general = p1.general + p2.general
        };
    }
}
```